# I want a x value(double) from the user. But when the tried to enter string.program crashes. How can i fix that

Tags: c#

I want a value beetween `3` and `30` from the user. When the user enter string values, my **program crashes**. I want to fix this. I want my program says `"Please enter x beetwen 3 and 30"` when the user enter string.

```
double x;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter x beetwen 3 and 30");

    x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    if (x > 3 && x < 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
} while (!(x > 3 && x < 30));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Programs that crash typically give some reason for doing so (i.e. an exception). It seems very strange that this wasn't made available to you by the debugger.

Comment: "When the user enter string values" - what values? and in what locale? The string `"abc"` won't work well with `Convert.ToDouble`, for example

Comment: check if the double value is in correct format by Double.Tryparse.

Answer (score 6):

Not every `string` value can be converted to `double` (e.g. `"bla-bla-bla"`) that's why you should use [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) (which returns `false` on incorrect input) instead of `Convert.ToDouble` (which throws exception):

```
  double x;

  do {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter x beetwen 3 and 30");
  } 
  while (!(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x) && x > 3 && x < 30));

  ...
```